# Is it viable to use Drupal/Ubercart for an international store? Do any payment gateways support it?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I am picking tools to use for an international store. Company sells training and products in North America, Europe and a few other places. The existing store in the United States (Drupal/Ubercart/Authorize.net) works great and serves all their needs.

Displaying product prices in different currencies are relatively easy to set up, and you can display the correct currency symbols and values depending on where services are rendered, where people want to ship to, etc (useful modules include u[c_multiple_currency](http://drupal.org/project/uc_multiple_currency), [uc_multiprice](http://drupal.org/project/uc_multiprice), [uc_cck_currency](http://uc_cck_currency)).

Are there viable Ubercart solutions to sell to other international markets using the same storefront? It is possible for any user to buy services/products through the US store, but paying in USD for a service offered in e.g. the Netherlands, when dealing with people based in the Netherlands is not acceptable.

The only payment gateway I could find that would accept payment in multiple currencies is Paypal. However, I am looking for a solution that would accept credit cards from international users and charge them in the correct currency. Authorize.net works great - will accept cards from anywhere and process them, but all transactions is in USD. It would be *extremely* problematic to charge someone €250 on the site and their final charge (after currency conversion) being e.g. €250.65 or something like it because of a delayed conversion.

Numerous people have asked this question, with very few useful insights and solutions (see for example [here](http://drupal.org/node/332750), [here](http://drupal.org/project/multicurrency), and [here](http://vintagedigital.net/content/how-add-multicurrency-support-ubercart), which presents a workaround-ish way of doing things).

**To be clear: Displaying prices in different currencies is easy. How can I bill credit cards internationally using the correct currency through a gateway that supports it, without having to do conversions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been through the same thing recently, but ended up making my own module to do the price handling. If it's done right, the prices will be displayed correct, even for order total etc. (See the `hook_uc_price_handler`)

This means that you will need to do two things to handle your problem.

1. Make sure the order only contain 1 currency, so you don't have one item costing €100 and another costing $100 (what would the total of that order be?) You could handle this by doing currency conversion if you wanted to, I believe that is how one of the modules you listed works.
2. When the payment is processed you need to send the correct currency to the payment provider. This already needs to be done in most cases as payment providers usually are able to collect in various currencies. Since most do the payment process via a hidden form that redirects or a inline form with hidden fields, you should be able to use `hook_form_alter` to set the currency to what you want. Depending on the payment module, this may be hard or easy.

Comment: Will mark this as the answer.. in short, it's not possible out of the box and requires some custom development. Some Ubercart ready gateways will actually accept transactions as described above (see e.g. http://www.usaepay.com/currency.htm). Downside is they are more expensive than my current provider (Authorize.net)